# How to write to DynamoDB Terraform code the table with values?

Tags: terraform, amazon-dynamodb

The json init code of DynamoDB table:

```
{
  "voter": {
    "S": "count"
  },
  "a": {
    "N": "0"
  },
  "b": {
    "N": "0"
  }
}
```

The DynamoDB table in AWS console:

[image: kk]

The TF code:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb_table_votes" {
  name           = "Votes"
  billing_mode   = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  #range_key      = "voter"
  #hash_key = ......

  stream_enabled   = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"

  dynamodb_attributes {
    name = "voter"
    type = "S"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "a"
    type = "N"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "b"
    type = "N"
  }

}
```

I don't know what to put for hashkey and rangekey as well as attributes part to create table with values a and b = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might need it, it's another resource "item" that should be used.

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb_table_votes" {
  name             = "Votes"
  billing_mode     = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key         = "voter"

  stream_enabled   = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"

  attribute {
    name = "voter"
    type = "S"
  }


}


resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "item1" {
  table_name = aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb_table_votes.name
  hash_key   = aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb_table_votes.hash_key

  item = <<ITEM
{
  "voter": {"S": "count"},
  "a": {"N": "0"},
  "b": {"N": "0"}

}
ITEM
}
```